# Coloring $K_n$ via edge-weight sums

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, graph-colorings

This is a question inspired by 
and tangential to "[A Question on 1, 2 ,3 Conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/q/147407/6094)"—and certainly
much easier!

Suppose one assigns a random edge weight among $\{1,2,3,\ldots,k\}$ to each
edge of $K_n$, and then sums the incident edge weights to each vertex
and assigns those as vertex weights.
For example, here is $K_5$ with edge weights from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$:

      [image: EVColoringPentagon]
(The top vertex has weight $13=3+1+4+5$.)
In this case, the vertex weights do not form a proper coloring, because there
are two vertices assigned weight $14$.

> What is the probability that $K_n$ will be properly colored when the
>   edge weights are chosen uniformly from among $\{1,2,3,\ldots,k\}$?

Empirically the function is well-behaved. Here is an accounting over $1000$ trials
on $K_5$ for each $k$ from $3$ to $20$:

      [image: EdgeVertexColoring]

---

As requested, a plot of Lucia's $e^{-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi }} n^{3/2}}{2 k}}$ for $n=5$ (with $k$ on the horizontal axis):

   [image: Lucia30]

Comment: You can estimate the probability that two particular vertices have the same sum and then use the union bound.

Comment: First guess:  Adding $n-1$ random elements (with replacement) from $1$ to $k$ gives some distribution on $(n-1)$ to $k(n-1)$.  Then one is essentially solving the birthday problem for $n$ objects from that distribution.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Would it be possible to plot $\exp(-\sqrt{3}n^{3/2}/(2\sqrt{\pi}k))$ on your graph?  Just eyeballing it, the fit seems like it would be reasonable.

Comment: @Lucia: I think you mean $1-\mathrm{exp}(...)$.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Thanks! I think I meant what I wrote, but you have the $n$ and $k$ reversed?  (So $n=5$ in what I had, and $k$ is the x-axis.)  Note that it should be exponentially close near zero on the x-axis (whereas what you have is exponentially close for large x).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke:  Just for clarity: when $n=5$ (coloring $K_5$) and $k=10$ from your plot the answer seems to be about $0.6$.  My conjecture gives $\exp(-\sqrt{3} 5^{1.5}/(20\sqrt{\pi}))$ which is about $0.58$.

Comment: @Lucia: In my excitement I switched $n$ and $k$, as you suspected---Sorry! Very close match. Brilliant! Congrats! :-)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Thanks for the plot!  The plot seems correct (or at least I'm happy since it matches my conjecture!), but there's a little typo in the formula just above the graph -- the numerator in the exponent should be $n^{3/2}$ and the denominator $k$.  Thanks again for the nice graph (and question!).

Comment: @Lucia: Typos fixed. Should not try to respond between meetings!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a heuristic which suggests that the right scale for $k$ is on the order of $n^{3/2}$, and predicts the actual probability for large $n$.   More precisely, we conjecture the following:  Let $n$ be large, and suppose $k$ is close to $t n^{3/2}$ and we have in mind that $t$ is of roughly constant size.  Then the probability that one gets a proper coloring is (as $n$ goes to infinity) asymptotically $\exp(-\sqrt{3}/(2\sqrt{\pi}t))$.  As $t$ goes to zero this is exponentially small, and as $t$ goes to infinity it tends to $1$ at a linear rate.

Here's the reasoning:  If $X_1$, $\ldots$, $X_n$ are chosen uniformly (with replacement) from $1$ to $k$, then the sum $X_1+\ldots+X_n$ has mean $n(k+1)/2$ and variance $n(k^2-1)/12$, and for large $n$ it is approximately normal with this mean and variance.  Therefore the sums for each of the $n$ vertices has mean $n(k+1)/2$ and wiggles around that on the scale of about $\sqrt{n}k$.  Let us imagine that different vertices have independent sums -- this is not quite true because they share an edge, but I would expect that effect to be small (this is a heuristic, not a proof after all!).  Then we have a situation like the birthday problem:  Pick $n$ numbers from an interval of length about $\sqrt{n}k$, what is the chance of a coincidence.  From the birthday problem we know that if $n^2$ is of size $\sqrt{n}k$ then there is a good chance of a coincidence.  (Note that for the proper coloring we want there not to be a coincidence of sums.)  This suggests that $k$ of size $n^{3/2}$ is the correct scaling. The actual formula was obtained by computing the analog of the birthday problem in this Gaussian setting 
(which is a nice exercise).

The only thing preventing this from being a proof is the lack of independence for the sums at two vertices -- I think this can be fixed, but will need a better probabilist than me!